# Running 'dotnet publish' updates the SDK to the wrong version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, publish

I'm writing a .NET Core 2.1 app however when publishing the wrong version of the SDK is loaded.

Below shows pre-publish state:

[image]

This is the post-publish state:

[image]

As far as I can tell I don't have any references to 2.1.6, infact I don't even think it's the latest version of 2.1.

As a side note, `dotnet restore` restores the correct version (2.1.0)

Furthermore the published project works as expected when deployed.

Here is the command:

`dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r win-x64 --framework netcoreapp2.1`

Anyone know a possible reason for this?

**EDIT**

`dotnet --list-sdks`

> 2.1.403 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
>
> 2.1.500 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

`dotnet --list-runtimes`

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

**EDIT 2**

Here is my .csproj file

[image]

Comment: `dotnet --list-sdks`/`dotnet --list-runtimes` says what? P.S. [ASP.NET Core Implicit Versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.2#implicit-versioning)

Comment: @Tseng Updated question

Comment: So 2.1.6 isn't the latest version but it is the latest version I have installed, for some reason it's updating to the latest minor version then.

Comment: Yea, you have no 2.1.0 runtime installed, the .NET Core SDK does roll-forward to the one installed on the system that does publish. See the linked docs: _For self-contained apps, the implicit version number is set to the major.minor.patch of the shared framework bundled in the installed SDK_ and generally, for portable apps the verison will be automatically rolled forward in case you don't have it specifically set (when `Version="x.y.z"` attribute is missing from PackageDependency in csproj, thats implicit versioning of the meta packages (the `.App` and `.All` meta package)

Comment: Okay, let me install the correct SDK and I'll get back to you!

Comment: Implicit versioning is the default, when creating new >= 2.1 projects, it ensures that your portable applications always use the latest packages with security fixes, same for self-containing application (the latest SDK at the time of the publishing installed on the machine that runs the publish command)

Comment: Using the implicit version is recommended, since it will always take the latest security fixed packages

Comment: Okay, I'll update my project to the latest minor version

Comment: You don't have to update it to the latest version, when your csproj is using implicit versioning (Remove Version attribute on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package if existing). Thats the whole point of implicit versions that it happens **automatically** once a newer runtime is installed on your system

Comment: Yeah I just need to download the latest SDK so my project works locally.

Comment: Unfortunately my project still references 2.1.0 despite relying on automatic updates. I still have issues when 2.1.7 is used since my project won't work locally (even after i've installed the 2.1.7 SDK). Some `dotnet` commands restore 2.1.0 and some 2.1.7.

Comment: What do your other 3 project reference? Does any of the 3 included projects references any `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages?

Comment: Only my main project references that package, it's reference is 2.1.1 though.

Comment: `CWS_API` = main project? Since `CWS_Web` doesn't have that. If your `CWS_API` requires a 2.1.1 package then you either need the 2.1.1 runtime installed (so the project compiles) or use the latest verison or implicit versioning too (then CWS_Api needs to have `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` in its csproj and target .NET Core (rather than .NET Standard since the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` targets netcore2.1). Changing it shouldn't affect your application/library be used on newer runtime. When you do publish/run the latest version of the specified package will be used